# Dictionaries in specific format

Tags: python, django, django-views

I need the below code in one specific format

```py
ROOM_CATEGORIES={
    ('Elt','Elite'),
    ('Lux','Luxury'),
    ('Sig','Signature')
    }
```

Above code I want `{'Sig':'Signature','Lux':'Luxury','Elt':'Elite'}` <---Like This

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort first, then call dict to convert sorted tuple:

```py
dict(
    sorted(ROOM_CATEGORIES, reverse=True)
)
```